# Back button is not visible in maui, using Prism

Tags: maui, cross-platform, prism

I created an application using MAUI and and prism. When I navigate using navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MauiPage1Page)) there is no back button.
[Missing back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vySO.png)

In navigation there is Navigation.NavigationStack there are 2 pages, but there is no back button. Is there any way how can I force to show it?

Back button will be on visible, and can navigate back on windows platforms.
I tryied all this methods but it won't help

```
    navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MauiPage1Page)) 
    navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof "/" + (MauiPage1Page)) 
    navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof "//" + (MauiPage1Page)) 
    navigationService.NavigateAsync("/" + nameof(NavigationPage) + "/" + nameof(MainPage));
    navigationService.CreateBuilder().AddNavigationPage().AddNavigationSegment(nameof(VeryMainPage)).NavigateAsync();
```